# Execute makefile in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, makefile, mingw

Hey everyone I'm currently searching a way to call the makefile inside of my batch file.

Presently that's what I get for the moment but i wont work cause mingw32-make.exe dosen't exist its just for an example.

```
cls
@echo off

setlocal
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\mingw\bin

echo *************************************************
echo This script compile you Windows sensor project
echo *************************************************
echo PREREQUISITE:
echo Have MinGW installed on your computer

pause

"C:\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" clean
```

What I want it's to call my makefile like : "make all" and it execute the makefile like how it should.

Here's my makefile

```
SRC = src/
BIN = bin/
OBJ = obj/

#Rule for Windows
all: libWin.a
    gcc -c main.c -o obj/main.o
    gcc obj/main.o bin/Win.a -o $(BIN)driveurCapteur

# Rule to compiler .c to .o
$(OBJ)%.o: $(SRC)%.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $<

# Rule to create the librairy
libWin.a: $(OBJ)com.o $(OBJ)state.o
    ar rcs $(BIN)$@ $^
```

My makefile actually work I tested it on eclipse but the fact is on the computer that they will compile my program they wont have eclipse configured on their computer so I'm using the solution of batch file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having.  Please be explicit about what doesn't work the way you want, how it should work instead, and any error messages you see currently.

Comment: All I want it's to call make all from my batch file.

Comment: Fine, and you have a call to make in your batch file.  What doesn't work about it?

Comment: I just don't know how to make a call to make. The one that we see in this batch file dosent work because mingw32-make.exe dosen't exist in the folder mingw/bin/.

Comment: ???  Well, you have to install make on your system somewhere.  Then invoke it from where it is installed.

Comment: But i have mingw installed so normally make come with it. no?

Comment: Well, that is an entirely different question than the one you asked.  I don't know much about the details of mingw so I can't say.  You should go find out: search the mingw installation directory for \*make\*.exe, or check the mingw documentation, or ask on the mingw forums etc.

Comment: Well in fact I didn't have installed msys that's why it didn't work, all I had to do was to change the environnement varraible and use the "call make" in my batch file and it work. if you want to write your solution as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only forget to install MSYS once it got installed i modified my batch file like this and everything works.

```
cls
@echo off

setlocal
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\mingw\bin;C:\mingw\msys\1.0\bin

echo *************************************************
echo This script compile you Windows  project
echo *************************************************
echo PREREQUISITE:
echo Have MinGW installed on your computer

pause

call make

echo Now your driver is ready

pause
```

Comment: You could add checks to your batch file to verify prerequisites for the user.  E.g., `if not exist "c:\mingw\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe" goto :no_msys_error`.  Also you can check the errorlevel after `make` to make sure `make` worked.  E.g., `if errorlevel 1 goto :make_error`.